# SQL Server : select latest time

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have a query that works well but has one problem, it displays other data I don't want.

The data is the latest of each username.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    l.USER_KEY AS id,
    l.USER_ID AS username, 
    gl1.CHAR_KEY AS char_id,
    gl1.NAME AS charname,
    gl1.GATENUM AS server,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), l.LOGINTIME, 100) AS user_time,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), gl1.OCCUR_TIME, 100) AS char_time
FROM LOG_CONNECT201211 AS gl1
    JOIN game.dbo.CHAR_INFOR AS g --character data
        ON gl1.CHAR_KEY = g.CHAR0_KEY OR gl1.CHAR_KEY = g.CHAR1_KEY OR gl1.CHAR_KEY = g.CHAR2_KEY
    JOIN login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN AS l --login data
        ON g.USER_KEY = l.USER_KEY
    JOIN (SELECT    char_key, max(OCCUR_TIME) as mostrecent  --game logs
            FROM    LOG_CONNECT201211 
            WHERE   KIND=20 OR KIND=21
            GROUP BY char_key) AS gl2
        ON gl2.char_key = gl1.char_key and gl2.mostrecent = gl1.OCCUR_TIME
WHERE l.CHECKLOGIN = 1
ORDER BY username DESC
```

That returns:

```
id      username    char_id name        map user_time           char_time   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3667    zr5970      11002   warpath     4   Nov 15 2012  8:54AM Nov  7 2012  6:31AM
3667    zr5970      11004   bloodfines  4   Nov 15 2012  8:54AM Nov  7 2012  6:33AM
3667    zr5970      11003   hanzhou     1   Nov 15 2012  8:54AM Nov 15 2012  8:54AM
14999   yvacosta    52086   Creams      1   Nov 15 2012  8:17AM Nov 15 2012  8:17AM
23433   yurich      1911481 abal        5   Nov 15 2012  8:34AM Nov  9 2012  4:05PM
23433   yurich      1911482 yurich      5   Nov 15 2012  8:34AM Nov 15 2012  8:30AM
23433   yurich      1911483 sharmaine   5   Nov 15 2012  8:34AM Nov 15 2012  8:35AM
10967   yubiwamoi   33376   Dwina       1   Nov 15 2012  4:33AM Nov 15 2012  4:33AM
```

So the data is correct, but I only want to return one row per username.

On this data the username returns 3, with 3 names, but the only name I want is that one with the latest char_time.

Example correct data:

```
id      username    char_id name        map user_time           char_time   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3667   zr5970      11003   hanzhou     1   Nov 15 2012  8:54AM Nov 15 2012  8:54AM
14999   yvacosta    52086   Creams      1   Nov 15 2012  8:17AM Nov 15 2012  8:17AM
23433   yurich      1911483 sharmaine   5   Nov 15 2012  8:34AM Nov 15 2012  8:35AM
10967   yubiwamoi   33376   Dwina       1   Nov 15 2012  4:33AM Nov 15 2012  4:33AM
```

Notice that I only displayed the data for `zr5970` with the latest `char_time`

Please advice, Thank you.

Comment: i just deleted my answer. can you sample data on your question? :D please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
    l.USER_KEY AS id,
    l.USER_ID AS username, 
    gl1.CHAR_KEY AS char_id,
    gl1.NAME AS charname,
    gl1.GATENUM AS server,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), l.LOGINTIME, 100) AS user_time,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), gl1.OCCUR_TIME, 100) AS char_time,
    rn = row_number() over (partition by l.USER_KEY order by gl1.OCCUR_TIME DESC)
FROM LOG_CONNECT201211 AS gl1
    JOIN game.dbo.CHAR_INFOR AS g --character data
        ON gl1.CHAR_KEY = g.CHAR0_KEY OR gl1.CHAR_KEY = g.CHAR1_KEY OR gl1.CHAR_KEY = g.CHAR2_KEY
    JOIN login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN AS l --login data
        ON g.USER_KEY = l.USER_KEY
WHERE l.CHECKLOGIN = 1
) X
WHERE rn=1
ORDER BY username DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

First select just the user name and the max time. This way you will have the correct number of rows. When you have that you can easily the other columns to your query...

Comment: Hello, can you elaborate? I'm not really well versed in sql.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.USER_KEY AS id,
    l.USER_ID AS username, 
    gl1.CHAR_KEY AS char_id,
    gl1.NAME AS charname,
    gl1.GATENUM AS server,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), l.LOGINTIME, 100) AS user_time,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), gl1.OCCUR_TIME, 100) AS char_time
from 
(select user_key, max(occur_time) as mostrecent
from log_connect2011
WHERE   KIND=20 OR KIND=21
group by user_key) a
join LOG_CONNECT201211 AS gl1 on a.user_key = gl1.user_key and a.mostrecent =        gl1.occur_time 
JOIN game.dbo.CHAR_INFOR AS g --character data
  ON gl1.CHAR_KEY = g.CHAR0_KEY OR gl1.CHAR_KEY = g.CHAR1_KEY OR gl1.CHAR_KEY = g.CHAR2_KEY
JOIN login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN AS l --login data
  ON g.USER_KEY = l.USER_KEY
WHERE l.CHECKLOGIN = 1
ORDER BY username DESC
```